# Create a circular file based on file size with serilog

Tags: serilog

I wonder if Serilog can be configured to create a circular logging file when a certain file size limit is reached it deletes older records.

I've already tried to configure it with the out of the box (File) writer

```
 "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "c:\\temp\\MyFile.txt",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 200,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 1
        }
```

And I've explored the sink "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate" already.

But all these packages give me a rolling file based upon size but are creating each time new log files.

Comment: there is a clone of this question in the last week or two that I answered - TL;DR its not likely to make sense to implement. However it has not been formally requested as a thing in a Github Issue in serilog/file and it might not hurt to have a canonical place to discuss it. (nlog and log4net do it _almost_ as you want, but it has its problems to rename a file thats being backed up etc)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54173333/11635